# How to persist layout of commit/diff window in Xcode 12.4

Tags: xcode

In the diff window of Xcode (Source Control -> Commit..., Cmd-Opt-C) is it possible to persist the size of the left navigation section? I like to resize the navigator bar to be able to see the filenames a bit better, but it gets reset at every invocation.

[image: Screenshot of Xcode diff window]

Comment: I would be very interested in a solution as well... this has been getting annoying

Comment: This is a known bug, I think... Did you try whether it's fixed in 12.5? If not, I would just use a better diff tool. I use Sourcetree plus BBEdit for this sort of thing.

Comment: @matt Yep sill an issue in 12.5. Sourcetree/BBEdit would work but it's hard to beat the convenience of the integrated diff right in there.

Comment: Well there's your answer so file a bug and move on, I'd say...

Comment: Filed a bug as FB9090794. I was hoping there would be some secret magic property to set somewhere to force the pane to a certain size as a workaround maybe.